# How are symbols displayed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

If I say `sym1 = Symbol();`, is `Symbol` function working like below function `g`,

```
> g = function(){
|     return 2; //return some random unique value based on some internal algo
| }
    g()
> var sym1 = g();
> sym1
    2
```

Now when I do `var sym1 = Symbol();`, and log `sym1`, the console displays `Symbol()` instead of displaying the value returned by the `Symbol` function.

So here's my question: How does the `Symbol` function work? How is the console able to display `Symbol()` instead of some value when you type `sym1`? Can we write such function?

Comment: What's this `window['Symbol']` vs `Symbol`, does it matter for your question?

Comment: What engine (ES6 implementation) or transpiler are you using?

Comment: @Bergi I prefer dictionary notation. so I wrote `window['Symbol']`

Comment: @overexchange What is purpose of using `Symbol(description)` ? What is expected result ?

Comment: @Bergi I still need clarity on javascript implementation version/ECMASCRIPT version/JS engine version. So I cannot answer you question. I think am using chrome version 44(as beginner)

Comment: @overexchange: Ah, Chrome 44, that's all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `Symbol` is just a function, similar<sup>1</sup> to an arbitrary `function g() { return something }`.

However, unlike the example `g` in your question, it does not return numbers, but [*symbols*](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-symbols/), which are a new primitive value type in ES6.

> When I say `sym1`, console displays `Symbol()` instead of displaying the value returned by function Symbol.

What do you think is the value returned, and what do you think how it should be displayed?

The number your `g` function returned is just some collection of 64 bits<sup>2</sup>. Somehow<sup>3</sup>, the console derives a base 10 string from that to display the number with the digits you expect.

Now, what is a symbol? It's just a value with an identity, and we don't even know how it is implemented. It's not immediately clear how that could be displayed, or if at all. It's not a number, it's not a string. Maybe some kind of id<sup>4</sup>?

ES6 however has taken a precaution against this, and every symbol is given a [description string](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type)<sup>5</sup> that can be passed as an optional argument to the `Symbol` function. Also, ES6 does specify how symbols should be displayed as string in [§19.4.3.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-symbol.prototype.tostring). And that's typically what the console uses.

Pretty much this "descriptive string" resembles the way the call to `Symbol` looked, e.g.

```
var sym1 = Symbol("my description");
console.log(sym1.toString()); // "Symbol(my description)"
console.log(sym1); // Symbol(my description)6
var sym2 = Symbol();
console.log(sym2.toString()); // "Symbol()"
console.log(sym2); // Symbol()6
```

<sub>1: However, it's a plain function, not a constructor, and cannot be called with `new`.

2: plus some kind of type information that it's a number, to give the 64 bits a meaning

3: to be explicit, the console probably uses [`.toString` for numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.prototype.tostring) when it encounters a number

4: Chrome displays such for every object when you take a heap snapshot with the dev tools, for example

5: So yeah, it's a bit more than the unique identity

6: implementation-dependent, depends on your `console`</sub>

Comment: Emphasis is not on what doe `Symbol` function returns. Emphasis is on why console shows `Symbol()` when you type `sym1`? how is that possible?

Comment: @overexchange: Right, I just took care of that :-)

Comment: For your point: "May be some kind of id" ## Could be anything but it MUST be part of implementation aspect of function abstraction `Symbol`, that implementation part can be changes anytime, by the author of `Symbol` function(if required). It is like storing a rational number in two element *array* as part of implementation and this implementation aspect may change to using two distinct number types to store num & denom later. Am I?

Comment: A well explanation.
But when we do `sym` and `sym.toString()`  in iojs repl we get Symbol() and 'Symbol()' .

Comment: @overexchange Yes, this is pretty much implementation-specific. Since there is no spec for the console, they could choose to display whatever they want - supposedly something that is useful to the developer using their tool - and can change at any time. But ES6 does specify what happens when you try to stringify a symbol, i.e. when calling `sym.toString()` or `String(sym)` on it. Also it specifies that doing `""+sym` throws etc.

Comment: The returned value(id or whatever) **MUST** be implementation specific, because the algorithm of returning the nature of value may change in future. So, console can't change the nature of displaying value accordingly. I **wish**, this was the actual reason above in terms of not displaying the actual value on console.

Answer (score 0):

> Is window['Symbol'] function working like below function g,

Not certain about actual Question ? Though, appear "no"

> Here is the confusion, when I say, > sym1 console displays Symbol()
>   instead of displaying the value returned by function Symbol

`Symbol()` does not *return* a `function` , but a *"unique and immutable data type and may be used as an identifier"*

See [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

> A `symbol` is a unique and immutable data type and may be used as an
>   identifier for object properties. The symbol object is an implicit
>   object wrapper for the symbol primitive data type.

```js
var sym = Symbol("foo");
var obj = {};
obj[sym] = 1;
console.log(obj.sym); // `undefined`
console.log(Object.keys(obj)) // `[]`
console.log(obj[sym]); // `1`
```

See also [ES6 In Depth: Symbols](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-symbols/)

Comment: Did I say that `Symbol()` is a function? Did you get my question in first place? I said `Symbol` is a function.

Comment: @overexchange _"Did I say that Symbol() is a function?"_ _"Here is the confusion, when I say, > sym1 console displays Symbol() instead of displaying the value returned by function Symbol."_ http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31895870/3 _"Did you get my question in forst place?"_ Not entirely ?, is purpose of using `Symbol` ? to set immutable identifier of a property within an object ?

Comment: OK. Do me a favour, write a function `f` such that, when you declare `var g = f();` console should show the value as `f()` when you type `g` on console. This is what is happening in my question above, when you type `sym1` console shows `Symbol()`. Did you get the question now?

Comment: @overexchange _"OK. Do me a favour, write a function f such that, when you declare var g = f(); console should show the value as f() when you type g on console. This is what is happening in my question above"_ ? Not certain how related to `Symbol()` ?

Comment: how related? `Symbol` is a function and `f` is also a function.

Comment: @overexchange _"how related? Symbol is a function and f is also a function. "_ See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol  "A symbol is a unique and immutable data type and may be used as an identifier for object properties." As described , `Symbol()` utilized as unique immutable  _identifier_ . What is expected result of using `Symbol()` ?